# Call an image in Javascript from address bar?

Tags: javascript

I don't know anything about JavaScript, but this shouldn't be too hard. In CSS there was a little trick where you could move an image around on a site, like with

```
background: url(http://site.com/image.png) no-repeat 16px 25px;
```

and it'd draw the image 16 pixels over and 25 pixels down. I was just wondering if there was a way to do that in JavaScript so I could play around with other sites a little.

Comment: You mean like using a Sprite? And yes you can do it in JavaScript - you can modify the `style` property of an element, specifically the `backgroundPosition` value

Comment: Solution is already posted here, but two remarks: 1. This is no "trick" in CSS, it is simply the purpose of CSS. 2. What has the question in the title to do with your actual question?

Comment: You can use the console through the dev tools in the browser to modify a website as per the answers McGarnagle and Diodeus gave you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
document.getElementById('something').style.backgroundPosition="10px 50px"
```

Or use variables:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 50;
document.getElementById('something').style.backgroundPosition= x + "px" + y + "px";
```

....then you can run an animation loop or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `style` property of the DOM object, and set `backgroundPosition`:

```
document.getElementById('myobjectid').style.backgroundPosition = "16px 25px";
```